# Bad Argument error as I try to add noise to an image with Keras preprocess function

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing, keras, computer-vision

To perform image-preprocessing, I was trying to use the [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) class from Keras. Here is how used it:

```
    data_generator = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range = 60,
        width_shift_range = 0.1,
        height_shift_range = 0.1,
        brightness_range = [0.5, 1.5],
        shear_range = 0.01,
        zoom_range = [0, 1],
        horizontal_flip = True,
        vertical_flip = True,
        preprocessing_function = preprocess_other
   )
```

The `preprocessing_function` attribute has been assigned a function named `preprocess_other` as defined below:

```
    def preprocess_other(image):
        flip = np.random.random()
        if flip > 0.5:
            # Add noise
            blank_image = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
            cv2.randn(blank_image, 0, 5)
            noisy_image = cv2.add(image, blank_image)
            return noisy_image
        else:
            # Return the original image
            return image
```

The role of this function is to add noise to an image with a probability of 0.5.

As I start the training process (training the CNN), it works for a few seconds but fails due to some error with the `preprocess_other` function with an error saying:

```
error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:683:
error: (-5:Bad argument) When the input arrays in 
add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types,
the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 
'arithm_op'
```

I debugged but could not understand the reason for it. Am I trying to add the noise in an incorrect way? How could I correct this error?

Comment: Try: `blank_image = np.zeros(image.shape, image.dtype)` or `np.zeros_like(image)`. *Also, if you are not flipping the image, please do not name your switch variable* `flip` :) I recommend you to check, but I think at this point your image may be in `[0,1]` range, so `[0, 5]` might be too much noise.

Comment: @Berriel Okay! I have applied the rescaling of `1./255` but when the function is called the max is at `255`, so `5` would be okay, I guess.

Comment: Sure, always good to check, that is why I said. Did my first suggestion helped solving the issue you were having?

Comment: @Berriel Yes. That was the mistake. You could post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `image` and `blank_image` have different types.

You can change:

```
blank_image = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
```

to:

```
blank_image = np.zeros(image.shape, image.dtype)
```

or to:

```
blank_image = np.zeros_like(image)
```